# Breakpoints in embedded scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying V8 out in a small test environment, where I have a custom html, with embedded JS scripts. I'm connecting to the Dev Tools trough Websocket, and its working well except for the Script debugger panel.

I'm creating the ScriptOrigin like this:

```
v8::ScriptOrigin{ fileNameValue, lineNumValue, colNumValue }
```

fileNameValue can be the same for multiple scripts, as there are many embedded scripts in a file.

The DevTools only shows one entry for each fileNameValue I submit, but it only displays the content of the last submitted script.

Is there a way to provide the full html, along with the embedded scripts, and map the scripts with the lineNum and colNum values?